# In an ubuntu terminal I would like to batch re-size images

Tags: find, imagemagick-convert

I've got like 500 images to resize, I'm not going to do that in gimp, a terminal solution would suit me best. I'm on ubuntu 14.04.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802606/how-to-batch-resize-images-in-ubuntu-recursively-within-the-terminal) question about batch resizing using Imagemagick and I guess that is partly what I'm after (I don't care about the recursive part). I need to resize all images so that the longest side of the image will be say 600 pixels. There are images where that will be the width and some where that is the height.

So I guess something like:

```
find . -name "*.jpg" | xargs convert -resize ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not on topic on Stack Overflow. A Google search e.g. for `batch resize images imagemagick` should get you all you need though!

Comment: I found an answer to a similar question on stackoverflow, only this didn't cover the question I had. But perhaps I could try asking this question on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use such command :

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -exec convert -resize 50% {} ... \;
```

`{}` applies for all found jpg files.