# Batch resize images within folders and keep folders structure?

Tags: imagemagick, mogrify

I have a folder of HD images, +2000px width :

```
+ /img/
   +- /bikes/: few images here (jpg,png,svg)
   +- /cars/ : few images here
   +- /cats/ : few images here
   +- /dogs/ : few images here
   +- /...
```

I would like to bach resize the whole into 200px width images (same ratios) yet keep the folder structure.

**How to do so ?**

Comment: A Google search for `imagemagick resize recursive` seems to yield good results

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802606/how-to-batch-resize-images-in-ubuntu-recursively-within-the-terminal I think the size argument for resizing images to 200 px width is `-resize 200x`

Comment: Do you mean to overwrite the original images, or create new, smaller files with new names?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I mean to create new ones, either in same folder with a `-small` or in a parallel folder-tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this, but please make a backup first!

```
find . -depth -type d \! -name '.' -exec bash -c 'cd $0 || exit; mkdir thumbs 2> /dev/null; shopt -s nullglob; mogrify -path thumbs -resize 200x *.jpg *.svg *.png ' {} \;
```

which will get you a subdirectory called `thumbs` in each directory with the smaller versions in there

Comment: It works. There was a bug with svg files that I bypassed by adding `-format png`, my command is now : `find . -depth -type d \! -name '.' -exec bash -c 'cd $0 || exit; mkdir thumbs 2> /dev/null; shopt -s nullglob; mogrify -path thumbs -resize 128x -format png *.jpg *.svg *.png *.tif' {} \;
`